# ActionLink does not create the right link

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is super straight forward, but somehow it is not working.  Can you please take a look?

on my page I have:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("My Recipes", "Index", "Recipes")%>
```

and i have the following controller:

```
namespace MyWebSite.Controllers
{
    public class RecipesController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Recipes/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

the html that is generated is:

```
<a href="">My Recipes</a>
```

while I expect it to be:

```
<a href="/Recipes/Index">My Recipes</a>
```

My controller is named: RecipesController.cs and is in the Controllers folder with all my other controllers?

Whats wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: You have messed up with your routes, haven't you? Show them please so that this could be confirmed.

Comment: yup. thanks . will fix you answered it!

Comment: posted my comment as answer so that you can accept it and close this question.

Comment: @Darin, write your comment as an answer and I will mark it as such

Comment: posted as answer, feel free to accept once the timeout expires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have messed up with your routes.